# drush failing with autoload.php failed to open stream

Tags: php, drupal, composer-php

I searched the whole drupal directory but I didn't find the autoload.php file. I see the error when enabling modules using drush on the command line.

Here is the exact error

```
include(sites/all/modules/contrib/guzzle/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory composer_autoload.module:24                           [warning]
include(): Failed opening 'sites/all/modules/contrib/guzzle/vendor/autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')                      [warning]
composer_autoload.module:24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen this error before, but I think it's telling you that you have to install composer, which is now a requirement for Drush.  See the installation instructions for Drush:   http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/#composer-one-drush-for-all-projects.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed by installing composer binary, rerunning drush dl composer and drush dl guzzle then went inside guzzle and ran ./composer.phar install